# Is there any advantage of using size_t over int in this code?

Tags: c++, c++17

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
 
int main()
{
    std::array myArray { 7, 3, 1, 9, 5 };
 
    // Iterate through the array and print the value of the elements
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < myArray.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << myArray[i] << ' ';
 
    std::cout << '\n';
 
    return 0;
}
```

It is stated that
*There is a signed/unsigned mismatch. The size() function and array index parameter to operator[] use a type called size_type.  Our loop counter/index (variable i) is a signed int. Therefore both the comparison i < myArray.size() and the array index myArray[i] have type mismatches.*

I understand the statement, but what is the consequence of this mismatch?
My IDE (VS2019) neither gives a error nor a warning. Are there any performance benefits from using std::size_t in place of int in this code?

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef> // std::size_t
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    std::array myArray { 7, 3, 1, 9, 5 };
 
    for (std::size_t i{ 0 }; i < myArray.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << myArray[i] << ' ';
 
    std::cout << '\n';
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes.  `size_t` is guaranteed to be able to represent all values up to and including `myArray.size()`  (which returns `size_t`).   An `int` is not guaranteed able to represent all those values, and - if an overflow occurs - the result is undefined behaviour.   More generally, however, I would either use iterators to control the loop (not indices) for C++ predating C++11 or, from C++11, use a range-based `for` loop.

Comment: "It is stated" where?